# Asp.net XMLwriter CData Escape Characters

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, cdata

I use ASP.net VB.net to write a XML file.

In one of the element which is called "Description" i have to add a "`<![CData[Class : <b>Class Name</b><br>Price: 100,000.00]]>`".

Using,

```
strDes = "<![CDATA[Class : <b>" + myReader.GetSqlValue(4).ToString + 
    "</b><br>Price: " + myReader.GetSqlValue(7).ToString + "]]>"
XMLwrite.WriteElementString("description", strDes.ToString)
```

But when i generate the XML file, it gives

```
<description>&lt;![CDATA[Class : &lt;b&gt;Residential - Site Built&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;Price: 100,000.00]]&gt;</description>
```

Comment: so, what is the issue with that? do you want <br> to be interpreted as a new line? If so, use vbCrLf instead (i.e. + "</b>" + vbcrlf + "Price................".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use the XML APIs to create XML. The CDATA you were generating should have been generated by the XmLWriter API. Try this:

```
strDes = "Class : <b>" + myReader.GetSqlValue(4).ToString + _
    "</b><br>Price: " + myReader.GetSqlValue(7).ToString
XMLwrite.WriteStartElement("description")
XMLwrite.WriteCData(strDes);
XMLwrite.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: I did this already. Had a hunch. However thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a CDATA section, you can use [WriteCData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writecdata.aspx) method instead.